# How to rotate relative points in degrees?

Tags: linear-transformations, transformation, rotations

I have 4 points in range [0.0, 1.0] representing the top-left and bottom-right corners of a bounding box.

For example: `[0.25 0.33 0.71 0.73]`

In other words, the first pair (in `(y, x)` format) means that the point is 25% down the top of the image, and 33% from the left. The second pair means that the bottom right point is located 71% from the top of the image and 73% from the left.

#### Question

If I now rotate the image by N degrees, how do I compute where those 4 points should be? To be more specific, I really only care to rotate the image 90, 180, 270 degrees.

[image]

*Left: original image, not rotated. Right: image rotated 90 degrees.*

Comment: Which software are you using?

Comment: I'm wanting to do this by hand, using a pencil and paper.

Comment: The point of having the box defined relative to the image sides is precisely that you dont need to rotate or scale the box. I.e., whatever rigid transform you do to the image should not affect the box since it is defined relative to the image.

Comment: I think the relative points is so the box scales if the image scales. But if you rotate the image, the box would need to be rotated as well. Think of a tall, skinny box on the left side of the image, which bounds, say, a stop sign. If you rotate that image 90 degrees, the stop sign is now sideways across the top of the image, so you'd want the bounding box to likewise be rotated such that it is horizontal (wide and not tall) like the object it is bounding on the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transformation you require  is:
$$ y’ = y \cos \theta  + x \sin \theta $$ 
$$x’ = -y \sin \theta+ x \cos \theta$$

Also don’t forget that when programming $\ cos \theta$ and $ \sin \theta$  needs to be in radians and not degrees. To convert from degrees to radians multiply by $\pi/180$.

You will note that the above formula is greatly simplified if the rotation angles are multiples of $90 \deg$.

For 0 degrees,  $y’ = y, \; x’ =  x $

For 90 degrees, $ y’ = x, \;  x’ = -y $

For 180 degrees,$ y’ = -y, \;x’ = - x $

For 270 degrees, $y’ = -x, \;x’ =  y $

If the final coordinates all have to be positive, as is the case for many image processing contexts, this should be modified to

For 0 degrees,  $y’ = y, \;  x’ =  x $

For 90 degrees, $ y’ = x, \;x’ =1 -y $

For 180 degrees,$ y’ = 1-y, \;x’ =1 - x $

For 270 degrees, $y’ =1 -x, \;  x’ =  y$

Finally, I note that the order of $x$ and $y$ coordinates that you use (although used in image processing  fairly often) are reversed to the standard math convention so be careful if you are searching for other  solutions on the internet that you are reading the correctly!

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Based off [Martin Roberts](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/575045/martin-roberts) answer, here's my complete solution:

```
  // values in absolute pixels
  box = [y_min, x_min, y_max, x_max];

  // Make points relative to image
  pct = [box[0] / height, box[1] / width, box[2] / height, box[3] / width];
  //^
  //|
  //+--------+
  //         |
  //         v
  rot90 = [pct[1], 1 - pct[2], pct[3], 1 - pct[0]];
  // ^
  // |
  // +--------+
  //          |
  //          v
  rot180 = [rot90[1], 1 - rot90[2], rot90[3], 1 - rot90[0]];
  // ^
  // |
  // +--------+
  //          |
  //          v

  rot270 = [rot180[1], 1 - rot180[2], rot180[3], 1 - rot180[0]];
```

[image]

- As a minor implementation detail, although not all images in my dataset were squares, they were deliberately reshaped to be squares because of the neural network model where they'll be used.
- The reason for the reversed (x, y) points, that's because [TensorFlow's tf.image.draw_bounding_boxes](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/draw_bounding_boxes) expects the points in that order.